# How to return an error when $addToSet does not add an item because it already exists in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following schema which contains a property with an array:

```js
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add a title"],
    },
    users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  },
);
```

In my project controller, I'm trying to add users to this array without getting a duplicate user. So I use $addToSet. It works fine but it doesn't return an error when there is a duplicate user.

```js
const project = await Project.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: id },
  { $addToSet: { users: userID } },
  { new: true }
);
```

How can I detect that it didn't add a user (because the user already exists in the array) and return an error?

Comment: well, if it doesn't return an error it must return an empty array? then check the length of the array and send appropriate response

Comment: @AR It returns the updated project, not an empty array. We can check for the length of the array if the array was empty from the start. What if we already have users in the array?